How to solve no unicode mapping error from PDFBox
I have a PDF file that has been compressed by Adobe, and I used PDFTextStripper from pdfbox to extract the PDF text content as blank, however there are multiple errors similar to the following:
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font [422] |  | No Unicode mapping for CID+63 (63) in font BFLONM+SimSun,Bold-GBK-EUC-H

How can we solve the coding problem?
I tried using chatgpt to help me analyze, as shown in the picture:

The embedded font of PDF with [FAAAAH+SimSun, Bold] can be parsed, while [BFLONM+SimSun, Bold-GBK-EUC-H] cannot be parsed.I suspect it may be related to GBK encoding

Note: me as many developers will not follow random links from random people, so please include images directly in the answer. In any case: Could you identify one of such symbols? And make a guess on what Unicode code should it have? It would help debugging.

I don't know how to directly display pictures.

@Giacomo i.static.net is where images uploaded to stackoverflow go, and yiCarlos being new has not the permissions to inline images. I inlined his images for him.

Which version do you use? And please correct spelling of the program you are using

The source PDF is quite private and difficult to display

@GiacomoCatenazzi is pdfbox2.0.8

@KJ The PDF has not been destroyed. It was compressed by Adobe and the embedded font became [BFLONM+SimSun, Bold-GBK-EUC-H]. The content was parsed as blank using pdfbox. The error indicates that the encoding is not mapped

The current PDFBox 2.0.* version is 2.0.32. Why are you using a version from 2017?

And AFAIK it didn't support complex scripts. In any case, you should edit the question to add new information. And with such compressed and complex documents, you may use the other way: OCR.

@TilmanHausherr The version still has the same issue

Try running the program again with the Linux environment variable LANG set to zh_CN.UTF-8. Do not test the program in a Windows environment.

I can't tell much without having the file. "No Unicode mapping" means the unicode isn't there. Maybe there is more log output, if there is please include it. Try also copy & paste from Adobe Reader.

Unfortunately, your issue is difficult to analyze (let alone resolve) without the PDF in question (or another PDF, showing the same symptoms for the same reasons). Apparently the ToUnicode maps are incomplete in your PDF. Then one usually has to resort to equivalent information from other sources, e.g. the ROS or the font file itself. But even those sources not always are helpful. Nonetheless, another possibility is a deficiency in PDFBox, but analyzing that possibility requires the file.
